# T-SQL Delete a node from XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need help, deleting the Error node where the TabID ="Claim",  I'm, using Sql server 2012

```
<ClaimErrors ClaimID="73">
  <Error ErrorMessage="offer timeframe" TabID="Offer" FieldName="PostMarkDate" ErrorType="FrontEnd" NoteID="2" />
  <Error ErrorMessage=" code is not valid" TabID="Claim" FieldName="None" NoteID="3811257" ErrorType="BackEnd Error" />
</ClaimErrors>



declare @XML table (data xml)
INsert into @XML select '<ClaimErrors ClaimID="73"><Error ErrorMessage="offer timeframe" TabID="Offer" FieldName="PostMarkDate" ErrorType="FrontEnd" NoteID="2" />
<Error ErrorMessage="code is not valid" TabID="Claim" FieldName="None" NoteID="3811257" ErrorType="BackEnd" /></ClaimErrors>'
update @XML set  data.modify('delete //ClaimErrors/Error[text()][contains(.,"TabID=Claim")]')
```

I'm using data.modify('delete //ClaimErrors/Error/  but with no hope.

any help will be appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: Your query should work! this definitly works for me, do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @XML table (data xml)
INsert into @XML select '<ClaimErrors ClaimID="73"><Error ErrorMessage="offer timeframe" TabID="Offer" FieldName="PostMarkDate" ErrorType="FrontEnd" NoteID="2" />
<Error ErrorMessage="code is not valid" TabID="Claim" FieldName="None" NoteID="3811257" ErrorType="BackEnd" /></ClaimErrors>'
declare @var nvarchar(256)= 'Claim'
update @XML set  data.modify('delete (/ClaimErrors/Error[@TabID=sql:variable("@var")])[1]')
select data from @XML
```